# Event Tracking in Google A

Tags: google-analytics

I need to track count on specific links on my website. I m using GA for that.So here is the code I emebed to my page, but its doesint works. 
At the top of page there is:

```
    <script>
    var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
    ga("send", "event", 'outbound', 'click', 'url', {
    'transport': 'beacon',
    'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
    }););
    </script>

    <a href="example.aspx" onclick="trackOutboundLink('examplej.aspx'); 
    return 
    false;" class="button2 button-blue" target="_blank"><span class="icon-
    pin"> 
    </span> More</a>
```

and at the bottom:

```
    <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)
    {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new 
    Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)
    [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-
    analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-1065XXXXX-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you not see any events in your Google Analytics account? Have you waited long enough to give the data enough time to show up (48 hours)? Can you install the GA debug Chrome [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) and show the console output?

Comment: Hi , ye , its been 48 hours now, just there is no single events.

Comment: Can you install tge chrome extension then try clicking the link and copy/paste what you see in the Console tab of Chrome developer tools?

Comment: (index):122 Uncaught ReferenceError: trackOutboundLink is not 
        defined
        at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):122)
        onclick @ (index):122